# Error: Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

Hi coder i have try few things but it doesn't work so i thought i might get my desired answer here

i have a searchuser.aspx page in which i have a textbox, button and gridview when i go to that page i can view details of all users with edit and detele button when i enter name of the user and click on button i get the details of the user and when i click on edit link i can edit the details of the user but when i click on search user page and click on edit link of the gridview i get

```
Specified cast is not valid. error
```

this is my where i get error in my gridview

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IsEnable?">
                  <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkIsEnableEdit" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("Enable") %>'/>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkIsEnable" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("Enable")%>' Enabled="False" />// here i got this error
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

i use    `checked='%#<Convert.ToBoolean(Eval(Enable)%'>` 
but its not working

this is my code behind code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.GetGridData();
    }
}
protected void BindGrid()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from CreateUser where FirstName like'"+tbSearchUser.Text+"'", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ds.Tables[0].NewRow());
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        int columncount = GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
        GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
        GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
        GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = columncount;
        GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No Records Found";
    }
}
private void GetGridData()
{
    con.Open();
    string query = "Select * from CreateUser";
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
protected void btnSearchUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "Select * from CreateUser where FirstName like'" + tbSearchUser.Text + "'";
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
    da.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    //this.BindGrid();
}
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GetGridData();
}
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    BindGrid();
}
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating1(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string query = string.Empty;
    string userid = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["UserID"].ToString();
    TextBox FirstName = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtFirstName") as TextBox;
    TextBox LastName = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtLastName") as TextBox;
    TextBox DomainID = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtDomainID") as TextBox;
    TextBox EmailID = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEmailID") as TextBox;
    TextBox Password = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtPassword") as TextBox;
    TextBox ConfirmPassword = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtConfirmPassword") as TextBox;
    DropDownList RoleType = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlrole") as DropDownList;
    CheckBox IsEnable = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("chkIsEnableEdit") as CheckBox;

    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update CreateUser set FirstName='" + FirstName.Text + "',LastName='" + LastName.Text + "',DomainID='" + DomainID.Text + "',EmailID='" + EmailID.Text + "',Password='" + Password.Text + "',ConfirmPassword='" + ConfirmPassword.Text + "',RoleType='" + RoleType.Text + "',Enable='" + IsEnable.Checked + "' where UserID='" + userid + "'", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    BindGrid();
    //GridView1.DataBind();
}
protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    BindGrid();
}
protected void DeleteRecord(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    string userid = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["UserID"].ToString();
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "Delete FROM CreateUser where UserID='"+userid+"'";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        BindGrid();
        lblMessage.Text = "Record Deleted successfully.";
        // Refresh the data
        BindGrid();
    }
    catch (SqlException ee)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = ee.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        cmd.Dispose();
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
      }
   }
}
```

enable is bit in database. When i change my bit value to bool in my database i won't be able to get that datatype i dont know why

can you guys help me

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Have you tried `Checked='<%# (bool)Bind("Enable")%>'`?

Comment: yes it give me following Error The name 'Bind' does not exist in the current context

Comment: What about: `Checked='<%# Bind("Enable") != null ? (bool)Bind("Enable") : false %>`?

Comment: it is also showing same error mate do you wana see my code behind code

Comment: I was just making sure the column isn't coming up null.

Comment: if i use Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Enable"))%>' it showing me Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types error

Comment: Another attempt: `Checked='<%# Eval("Enable") != null ? (Bool.Parse(Eval("Enable").ToString()) ? "checked" : "") : "" %>`

Comment: It's coming as null then.

Comment: same error bool doesnt exist in this current context

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment, the column can hold null values (which isn't ideal for a true/false condition):

**UPDATED**

```
Checked='<%# Eval("Enable").GetType() != typeof(DBNull) ? Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Enable")) : false %>'
```

Comment: according to your answer i get String was not recognized as a valid Boolean error

Comment: if you wana see my code behind just let me know may be it will help me and you

Comment: Post it along with your question, please. Maybe the problem is in the DataSource.

Comment: in your present answer when i click on edit link my gridview show no record found means value comes from database in null

Comment: I ran out of ideas. Sorry.

Comment: This fixed my issue, thank you.